# Why is the hashed content not getting saved into the CSV file?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a column in a CSV file, `Original.csv`, which has a bunch of user IDs, some of which repeat, like following:

```
udid
d0155049772de9
8b57d8c7f1e5a31e4adaef5fe6c52df1ada7fcd5
8b57d8c7f1e5a31e4adaef5fe6c52df1ada7fcd5
465088425ceb38c62bf8d1d9cc33bcfab4fe4293
3eabe40461773086
3eabe40461773086
e24356719f086021
212b5b0415560be3
1c046451a3761ef51fbf52759748f66c98b02313
```

I want to process them in MATLAB later, so I wanted to hash and convert them into integers and store them in a new file, `New.csv`. This is my code:

```
require 'csv'

udids = []
id=[]

CSV.foreach('Original.csv', :headers=>true).map do |row|
    udids << row[0]
end

udids=udids.uniq
arrayHash=[]

for i in 0..udids.size-1
    arrayHash<<udids
    arrayHash<<i
end

hash = Hash[arrayHash.each_slice(2).to_a]

id=hash.values_at *udids

for i in 0..id.size-1
    logfile = File.new('New.csv',"w")
    logfile.print("#{id[i]}\n")
    logfile.close
end
```

Due to some reason I haven't able to figure out, the `New.csv` file is empty after running the code. What's the issue?

Edit: Is hashing for this program going to perform faster than simply comparing and checking if a user ID has been repeated before? Something like this:

```
CSV.open('New.csv', "wb") do |csv|
   CSV.foreach('Original.csv', :headers=>true).map do |row|
     unless udids.include?(row[0])
      udids << row[0]
    end
    csv<<udids.index(row[56]) + 1
    end
end
```

In either case, could you please say why one would perform faster over the other? My CSV has 60 million records, if that matters.

Comment: you are overwriting the file in each loop iteration.

Comment: finding a hash element is faster then finding array element, especially with 60 milions lines. but it may be a problem to hold the whole hash in memory.

Comment: if you write udids.include? it will compare your element against all 60 million elements. if you do this 60 million times, you are dead.

Comment: This is an XY Problem. You are asking how to work around a bad design decision which is Y. Your X question should have been, what is the best way to process 60 million lines in a CSV file and find specific records? Load the records into a SQLite database on disk and use SQL to find and extract the data. Look at [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) for a great way to manage this. The documentation will get you up and running quickly. Loading them into RAM isn't scalable.

Answer (score 1):

Without a deeper look on your complete code:

With

```
for i in 0..id.size-1
    logfile = File.new('New.csv',"w")
    logfile.print("#{id[i]}\n")
    logfile.close
end
```

You open the file `id.size-1` times, write one line and close it. In the end you have the file with the last entry.

It seems you want something like this

```
    File.open('New.csv',"w") do |logfile| #Open the file
      id.each{|one_id|                #loop on all ids
        logfile.print("#{one_id}\n")  #write one id in line
      }
    end       #Close the file
```