# How to sequentially create multiple CSV files in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, csv

Silly question, but I want to do some processing on a dataset and put them into different CSVs, like `UDID1.csv`, `UDID2.csv`, ..., `UDID1000.csv`. So this is my code:

```
for i in 1..1000
    logfile = File.new('C:\Users\hp1\Desktop\Datasets\New File\UDID#{i}\.csv',"a")
    #I'll do some processing here
end
```

But the program throws an error when running because of the `UDID#{i}` part. So, how to overcome this issue? Thanks.

Edit: This is the error:

```
in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:\Users\hp1\Desktop\Datasets\New File\udid#{1}\.csv (Errno::ENOENT)from C:/Ruby21/bin/hashedUDID.rb:38:in `new' from C:/Ruby21/bin/hashedUDID.rb:38:in '<main>'
```

Answer (score 2):

The `'` is one problem, another problem is the path.

In your posting the `New File` must exist as a directory. Inside this directory must exist another directories like `UDID0001`. This gets a `.csv` file.

Correct is (I don't use the non-rubyesk for-loop):

```
1.upto(1000) do |i|
    logfile = File.new("C:\\Users\\hp1\\Desktop\\Datasets\\UDID#{i}.csv", "a")
    #I'll do some processing here
    logfile.close #Don't forget to close the file
end
```

Inside `"` the backslash must be masked (`\\`). Instead you may use `/`:

```
logfile = File.new("C:/Users/hp1/Desktop/Datasets/New File/UDID#{i}/.csv", "a")
```

Another possibility is the usage of `%i` to insert the number:

```
    logfile = File.new("C:/Users/hp1/Desktop/Datasets/New File/UDID%02i/.csv" % i, "a")
```

I prefer to use `open`, then the file is closed with the end of the block:

```
    File.open("C:/Users/hp1/Desktop/Datasets/New File/UDID%04i/.csv" % i, "a") do |logfile|
      #I'll do some processing here
    end #closes the file
```

**Warning:**

I'm not sure, if you really want to create 1000 log files (The File is opened inside the loop. so each step creates a file.).
If yes, then the `%04i`-version has the advantage, that the files get all the same number of digits (starting with `0001` and ending with `1000`).

Comment: Ok, that worked! Thanks! As for why I need this, actually my original problem can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797346/why-is-the-hashed-content-not-getting-saved-into-the-csv-file
So, because the hashed array can't store so many values, I thought of partitioning my dataset into smaller manageable chunks, hashing them, storing them in separate CSV files (which is this question), & then compare them with subsequent hashings.

Comment: If this answer solves the problem of your question you should accept the answer.

Comment: for a thorough solution +1

Answer (score 0):

`#{}` can only be used in strings with double quotes `"`. So change your code to:

```
for i in 1..1000
  logfile = File.new("C:\Users\hp1\Desktop\Datasets\New File\UDID#{i}\.csv","a")
  # other stuff
end
```

Comment: Except that `#{}` is not a constructor :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(1..10).each { |i| logfile = File.new("/base/path/UDID#{i}.csv") }
```

You must use double quote (") when you need string interpolation.

Comment: how does this add to my existing answer?